# Cannot consume message from Kafka topic in Laravel

Tags: laravel, apache-kafka

I have to integrate kafka in a Laravel project, for that I use the [mateusjunges/laravel-kafka](https://github.com/mateusjunges/laravel-kafka) version 1.13 whose example code is defined as follows :

Producer Code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Junges\Kafka\Facades\Kafka;
use Junges\Kafka\Message\Message;

class KafkaProducerController extends Controller
{
    public function produce(Request $request)
    {
        $new_message = new Message(
            headers: ['header-key' => 'header-value'],
            body: ['key' => 'value'],
            key: 'kafka key here'  
        );
        
        $producer = Kafka::publishOn('ramses')->withMessage($new_message);
        $producer->send();
    }
}
```

Consumer Code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Junges\Kafka\Facades\Kafka;
use Junges\Kafka\Contracts\KafkaConsumerMessage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use App\Handlers\TestHandler;

class KafkaConsumerController extends Controller
{
    
    public function consume(Request $request)
    {
        $messageReceived = '';
        //Log::info("ramsi");
        $consumer = Kafka::createConsumer()
            ->subscribe('ramses')
            ->withBrokers('localhost:9092')
            ->withConsumerGroupId('group')
            ->withHandler(new TestHandler)
            ->build();
            
            $consumer->consume();

            return response()->make($messageReceived, 200);
    }
}
```

The Routes which call to the controllers :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


use App\Http\Controllers\KafkaProducerController;
use App\Http\Controllers\KafkaConsumerController;

Route::get('/produce', [KafkaProducerController::class, 'produce']);
Route::get('/consume', [KafkaConsumerController::class, 'consume']);
```

The handler :

```
<?php

namespace App\Handlers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Junges\Kafka\Contracts\KafkaConsumerMessage;

class TestHandler
{
    public function __invoke(KafkaConsumerMessage $message)
    {
        Log::debug('Message received!', [
            'body' => $message->getBody(),
            'headers' => $message->getHeaders(),
            'partition' => $message->getPartition(),
            'key' => $message->getKey(),
            'topic' => $message->getTopicName()
        ]);
    }
}
```

and finally, the kafka config :

```
<?php

return [
    /*
     | Your kafka brokers url.
     */
    'brokers' => env('KAFKA_BROKERS', 'localhost:9092'),

    /*
     | Kafka consumers belonging to the same consumer group share a group id.
     | The consumers in a group then divides the topic partitions as fairly amongst themselves as possible by
     | establishing that each partition is only consumed by a single consumer from the group.
     | This config defines the consumer group id you want to use for your project.
     */
    'consumer_group_id' => env('KAFKA_CONSUMER_GROUP_ID', 'group'),

    /*
     | After the consumer receives its assignment from the coordinator,
     | it must determine the initial position for each assigned partition.
     | When the group is first created, before any messages have been consumed, the position is set according to a configurable
     | offset reset policy (auto.offset.reset). Typically, consumption starts either at the earliest offset or the latest offset.
     | You can choose between "latest", "earliest" or "none".
     */
    'offset_reset' => env('KAFKA_OFFSET_RESET', 'latest'),

    /*
     | If you set enable.auto.commit (which is the default), then the consumer will automatically commit offsets periodically at the
     | interval set by auto.commit.interval.ms.
     */
    'auto_commit' => env('KAFKA_AUTO_COMMIT', true),

    'sleep_on_error' => env('KAFKA_ERROR_SLEEP', 5),

    'partition' => env('KAFKA_PARTITION', 0),

    /*
     | Kafka supports 4 compression codecs: none , gzip , lz4 and snappy
     */
    'compression' => env('KAFKA_COMPRESSION_TYPE', 'snappy'),

    /*
     | Choose if debug is enabled or not.
     */
    'debug' => env('KAFKA_DEBUG', true),
];
```

I have succeeded to produce message, I see created partitions about my topic at the broker level as you can see on this [image]

But, the consumer does not Log the message.

Can someone tell me what is wrong on this example or propose another way to integrate kafka inside a Laravel project ?

I precise I used the Laravel 10 version and PHP 8.1 for this example.

Comment: Try to use consumer: `$consumer = Kafka::createConsumer(['ramses'])->withHandler(new TestHandler)->build();` explanation: it uses configs already by default, and 'ramses' is topic name and based on this file: https://github.com/mateusjunges/laravel-kafka/blob/v1.13.x/src/Kafka.php You have to pass topic names in `createConsumer` method

Comment: also for for obviousness and distinguishing producer from message which was sent I recommend to write producer this way: `$message = new Message(headers: ['header-key' => 'header-value'], body: ['key' => 'value'], key: 'kafka key here');   $producer = Kafka::publishOn('ramses'); $producer->produce($message);`

Comment: code for producer does not work, it even gives an error call to undefined method produce,
same for the consumer I don't received message

Comment: @num8er it does not work for me, can you provide your entire code ? I mean the Laravel project so that I can test easily.